# Makefile - Compile object with different library

Tags: c, makefile, clang

I´m trying to create a Makefile that build a lib and compile the file. My problem is that depending on the %.c file I need to compile with different lib.

The SRC_MLX need the $(LFLAGS) and the SRC don´t. So the gcc compiler don´t allow me to compile the SRC with the LFLAGS. That´s the reason I need to separate.

I´ve tried this way:

```
SRCS =  $(DIR_SRC)/ft_utils.c \
        $(DIR_SRC)/ft_adt.c \
        $(DIR_SRC)/ft_circle.c \
        $(DIR_SRC)/ft_line.c \
        $(DIR_SRC)/ft_trgb.c \
        $(DIR_SRC)/ft_quadrilateral.c \
        $(DIR_SRC)/ft_player.c \
        $(DIR_SRC)/ft_color.c

SRCS_MLX =  $(DIR_SRC)/win_update.c \
            $(DIR_SRC)/ft_vars.c \
            $(DIR_SRC)/ft_image.c \
            $(DIR_SRC)/ft_map.c


$(NAME):    $(LIB_NAME)
            $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c -I. -I$(DIR_MLX) -L$(DIR_MLX) -L. $(LFLAGS) $(LIB_FLAG) -o $@ -g

$(DIR_OBJ)/$(OBJ).o:    $(DIR_SRC)/$(SRCS).c
                mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJ)
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -I. -I$(DIR_MLX) -o $@

$(DIR_OBJ)/$(OBJ_MLX).o:    $(DIR_SRC)/$(SRCS_MLX).c
                mkdir -p $(DIR_OBJ)
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -I. -I$(DIR_MLX) -L$(DIR_MLX) $(LFLAGS) -o $@

$(LIB_NAME):    $(OBJ_MLX) LIB_OBJ
                $(AR) $(LIB_NAME) $(OBJ)
                ranlib $(LIB_NAME)

LIB_OBJ:    $(OBJ)
                $(AR) $(LIB_NAME) $(OBJ)
```

In the example above I´ve tried to create a lib with one kind of files and after that create a lib with the first lib with the others files. But I keep getting this error:

```
Makefile:41: warning: overriding recipe for target '.objs/'
Makefile:37: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '.objs/'
make: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 454 s in the future
rm -f  .objs/ft_utils.o  .objs/ft_adt.o  .objs/ft_circle.o  .objs/ft_line.o  .objs/ft_trgb.o  .objs/ft_quadrilateral.o  .objs/ft_player.o  .objs/ft_color.o
rm -f libcub3d.a
rm -f main
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/src/win_update.c', needed by '.objs/win_update.o'.  Stop.
```

How can I compile this objects with different lib?

P.S. Those are my variables:

```
DIR_OBJ = .objs
DIR_SRC = src
DIR_LIB = lib
DIR_MLX = ./minilibx-linux
NAME = main
LIB_NAME = libcub3d.a
OBJ = $(patsubst $(DIR_SRC)/%.c, $(DIR_OBJ)/%.o, $(SRCS))
OBJ_MLX = $(patsubst $(DIR_SRC)/%.c, $(DIR_OBJ)/%.o, $(SRCS_MLX))
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra
LFLAGS = -lmlx -lm -lX11 -lXext -lbsd
LIB_FLAG = -lcub3d
AR = ar -rc
RM = rm -f
```

Comment: I see error messages referring to lines 37 and 41 of your Makefile... yet the Makefile you gave has less lines than that? Please post the Makefile that goes with the error message.

Comment: I just send it the part of the code where I thought the problem was.

Comment: ...devaluating the error message and leaving us guessing.

Comment: Just followed the rules:

```Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.```

Comment: No you didn't. "Reproducing the problem" means providing the error message *and the code necessary to **reproduce** the error message*. That's what I am trying to tell you. That error message contained two line numbers, very important information that points RIGHT to the problem -- **if** you have the Makefile with the matching lines.

Comment: Ok. Sorry if my question wasn´t enought for you to answer. Nevertheless other person focused more in help me than just complain. The question has been answered. I will try to do better questions in the future.

Comment: I am not "complaining". I am trying to teach you better debugging / asking better questions. Not only so your questions will be upvoted here on SO, but so that you get better at solving problems yourself. No offense intended whatsoever, and sorry if it seemed as if I was "complaining".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are definitely not right:

```
$(DIR_OBJ)/$(OBJ).o:    $(DIR_SRC)/$(SRCS).c
    ...
$(DIR_OBJ)/$(OBJ_MLX).o:    $(DIR_SRC)/$(SRCS_MLX).c
```

along with the way you've defined `SRCS` and `SRCS_MLX` and these:

```
OBJ = $(patsubst $(DIR_SRC)/%.c, $(DIR_OBJ)/%.o, $(SRCS))
OBJ_MLX = $(patsubst $(DIR_SRC)/%.c, $(DIR_OBJ)/%.o, $(SRCS_MLX))
```

Just expand the variables in the rule in your head, or else ask make to expand it for you with the `info` function, and you'll see it's definitely not right:

```
$(info output is '$(DIR_OBJ)/$(OBJ).o: $(DIR_SRC)/$(SRCS).c')
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I was so focus in trying to do 2 rules, that I didn´t see this. Thank you for the "info" tip, didn´t know this command.